# Select input select all options at once with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to select all option at once with JavaScript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```js
    function selectAll()
    {
     options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
     for ( i=0; i<options.length; i++)
     {
      options[i].selected = "true";
     }
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <select multiple>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="opel">Opel</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    
    <button onClick="selectAll();">Select All</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```